# Change Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture with Windows settings

Tags: windows, currentuiculture

I have the problem that

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture is de-DE
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture is de-CH.
```

When I change the keyboard layout to de-CH Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture is not changed to de-CH. What have I to do that this value will be changed?

The problem is that I get in WPF the ',' decimal separator instead of '.'

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.inputlanguagemanager.currentinputlanguage?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-input-inputlanguagemanager-currentinputlanguage

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question directly: keyboard layout is not UI Culture. `CurrentUICulture` is Windows language. Not sure about other Windows versions, but in Windows 11 it's `Settings -> Time & Language -> Language & Region -> Windows display language`:

[image: Windows display language]

**But** decimal separator in not defined by `CurrentUICulture`, but `CurrentCulture`, which is different. In Win11 it's Regional Format:
[image: Regional Format]

In general, correct strategy of proper decimal separator (as a part of general application localization) is a big question and could be solved in many different ways based of your user preferences/business expectation and so on. Possible options could be:

1. Just use current culture and believe that user will use separator of his culture
2. Force user to use only '.' and specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` while parsing
3. Try to parse number with both separators

and others...

Comment: Thank You for Your help. I would like to use option 1.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows 10 here the language Settings. Every setting is set to
Deutsch(Schweiz) except the language recognition.

[image]

But I get this:
[image]

I am using .NET 7